# SMB connection failed:(Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)

Tags: networking, smb

smbclient -L 10.129.235.72
//error msg
do_connect: Connection to 10.129.235.72 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT).

how to resolve this issue i'm facing this linux?